# how to download a video from Google drive?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I can download video and image, but it was not playable (file format isn't supported, or is the file corrupted?).
I get stuck to get the playable video from google drive.
Any help is appreciable.

-My button onclick to intent google drive.

```
open.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onClickOpenFile(v);
        }
    });


public void onClickOpenFile(View view) {
    fileOperation = false;

    // create new contents resource
    Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(mGoogleApiClient)
            .setResultCallback(driveContentsCallback);
}
```

Open list of folder and file of the Google Drive

```
public void OpenFileFromGoogleDrive() {

    IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
            .newOpenFileActivityBuilder()
            .setMimeType(new String[]{"image/jpeg", "image/png", "video/mp4"
                    , "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"})
            .build(mGoogleApiClient);
    try {
        startIntentSenderForResult(

                intentSender, REQUEST_CODE_OPENER, null, 0, 0, 0);

    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {

        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to send intent", e);
    }

}

final ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult> driveContentsCallback =
        new ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(DriveApi.DriveContentsResult result) {

                if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {

                        OpenFileFromGoogleDrive();
                }

            }
        };

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode,
                                final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {

        case REQUEST_CODE_OPENER:

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                video_url = "https://drive.google.com/open?id=" + mFileId.getResourceId();
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(video_url));
                startActivity(i);
            }
            break;

        default:
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            break;
    }
}
```